# D3 Line Chart into bindPopup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I’m a complete beginner to D3.js and I am trying to get a simple line chart into a leafletJS popup.

I am attempting to plot the values in the array against their index as practise.

This is the code that I have for the on click function:

```
point.on("click", function() {

  var div = $('<div style="width: 800px; height: 300px;"><svg/></div>')[0];
  this.bindPopup(div);
  this.openPopup();

  //data:
  var data = [3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 0, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 3, 6, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 9, 2, 7];

  // set scales:
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,data.length]).range([0, 300]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,10]).range([0, 300]);

  // create axes:
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

  //construct line:
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) {
      return x(i);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d);
    });

  var svg = d3.select(div).append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,-150)")
    .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("path").attr("d", line(data));

})
```

This is the result that I get in my popup:

[image]

I am totally clueless on everything from the scale, to there being no line, to the y axis being below the x axis.

Any direction here would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy I'm just starting out. So just a line graph appearing in the popup would be nice. I am using the example here: http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2579599

Comment: set up a jsfiddle so we can have a look

Answer (score 1):

You have `trasnalate` instead of `translate`in your xAxis, that would explain the shift of the x bar.

**Edit:** *my previous answer about reversing the `y` scale was incorrect. The following is more likely to be the cause of the problem:*

About the scale, you forgot to mention the domain:

```
 var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, 300]);
 var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([300, 0]);
```

Quoting the documentation:

> d3.scale.linear() : Constructs a new linear scale with the default domain [0,1] and the default range [0,1].

For `x` you can safely keep `data.length` as a maximum value, for `y`you'll likely need to change the value `10`to fit your needs (you can also look for a maximum over the data array). But in any case `[0,1]` is too short.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I have edited in the changes, but I'm getting very similar results to before.

Comment: @noob Ok I've edited my answer. Hope this work. If it doesn't look for the path in your DOM, the rest will depend on whether it's there or not.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the code and image of the popup. I am now getting some kind of plotting on the still rather awkward graph. Please could you have a look, if you have the time. Appreciate it!